# Adding only unique strings in a list with an addall() or similar method

Tags: java

Whats the smallest amount of code we can add to the statement

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```

so it only adds unique elements of list 2 to list 1?

I know we can do something like

```
list1.addAll(list2); 
list1 = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list1));
```

But i am creating two unnecessary objects (ArrayList, HashSet) to accomplish deduping, and also its not very readable to see the intent of using a HashSet. I am wondering if it can simply be done by calling a method such as list1.addUnique(list2) or in a more efficient way?

Comment: list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: Other than functional programming?

Comment: Use a loop rather than addAll.  There is no "add if not present" functionality on the List API.  And (BTW) using a HashSet for deduping with be more efficient for large lists.  That's the reason people use it.  (The complexity is O(N) with `HashSet` compared to `O(N^2)` if you dedup using `List.contains`)

Comment: If you are following advice of @StephenC then you better be using `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList` in that case, because the more frequent operation would be to access than adding.

Comment: The real problem with this question is that an answer requires you to either already understand complexity analysis ... or it requires us to give you a lesson in complexity analysis.  And we are not here to give lessons.  That's what teachers / training courses / text books are for.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - Actually no.  ArrayList versus LinkedList won't change the complexity.  Both will give `O(N^2)` performance.

Comment: @StephenC There will be `if` condition which has `list.contains()`. The `if` condition will be executed more than `list.add()`. So `LinkedList` has a upper hand here.

Comment: You are missing my point.  (Stupid analogy time, I'm afraid.)  LinkedList versus ArrayList is bicycle versus rickshaw.  Deduping using a HashSet / HashMap is like a jet plane.  It sound like you need a lesson in complexity analysis too.